# How can I export a mySQL #temp table to a .csv file within script?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, csv, sqlcmd

I'd like to write a script that allows me to export .csv files from 15-20 temporary tables I created, using a script instead of having to copy and paste in a separate `.csv` file and then save them down.

```
:!!sqlcmd -S server -d database-E -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON 
SELECT * FROM TABLE" -o "C:\Users\name\Documents\folder\filename.csv"
-W -w 1024 -s ","
```

I've tried this, which works (not formatting correctly) but it doesn't seem to be work at all for a temp table; the `.csv` file contains this.

```
Msg 208  Level 16    State 1     Server SERVERNAME
Invalid object name '#TEMPTABLE'.
```

I cannot obtain "elevated privileges" to be able to use BCP export, because I cannot write a stored procedure, create a new database, or access the command line. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temp tables are ephemeral; they do not persist across sessions.  Instead of creating temp tables, create actual tables, either in the database that you're working with, or in `tempdb`, then export the data from `tempdb`

An example:

`sqlcmd -S server -d database -E -Q "If Exists (select * FROM tempdb.sys.tables WHERE name = 'Tmp_DataExport1') drop TABLE tempdb..Tmp_DataExport1;"`

`sqlcmd -S server -d database -E -Q "SELECT TOP 5 * INTO tempdb..Tmp_DataExport1 FROM T_SourceTable"`

`sqlcmd -S server -d database -E -Q "SELECT * FROM tempdb..Tmp_DataExport1" -o "c:\temp\filename.csv" -W -w 1024 -s ","`

Comment: Thanks Alchemist. Unfortunately, I have don't have permission to create an actual table in the database because I don't have permission to do so. I'll try moving the table to tempdb, then exporting